# Why does this code not output anything after getting user input?

Tags: python

```
num_1 = int(input("Enter the first number >>>>"))
num_2 = int(input("Enter the second number >>>>"))

if num_1 > num_2:
    for i in range(num_1,num_2+1):
        print(i)
else:
    for i in range(num_1,num_2,-1):
        print(i)
```

What is the issue with this code? Once the user inputs the two numbers the program stops and nothing gets printed.

Comment: You are providing if `num1 > num2` then get `range(num1, num2)` which is not iterating because no elements span from `num1` to `num2`. Example, if `5 > 4`.. then `range(5,4)` doesnt give anything.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the logic the wrong way around. You need to check is num_1 is less than num_2 when counting up.

```
num_1 = int(input("Enter the first number >>>>"))
num_2 = int(input("Enter the second number >>>>"))

if num_1 < num_2:
    for i in range(num_1,num_2,+1):
        print(i)
else:
    for i in range(num_1,num_2,-1):
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num_1 = int(input("Enter the first number >>>>"))
num_2 = int(input("Enter the second number >>>>"))

if num_1 < num_2: # in here hace a less then sign and not > 
    for i in range(num_1,num_2+1):
        print(i)
else:
    for i in range(num_1,num_2-1): # In here you had a typo, it had a comma and as a result it was passing in 3 parameters
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your first and second numbers are being used incorrectly in range.

The range takes smaller number first and larger number second. You are providing if `num1 > num2` then get `range(num1, num2)` which is not iterating because no elements span from `num1` to `num2`

```
num_1 = int(input("Enter the first number >>>>"))
num_2 = int(input("Enter the second number >>>>"))

if num_1 < num_2:
    for i in range(num_1,num_2+1):
        print(i)
else:
    for i in range(num_1,num_2,-1):
        print(i)
```

```
Enter the first number >>>>5
Enter the second number >>>>3
5
4
```

Answer (score 0):

To count from high to low, you need to do more than reverse the step. If you have, for example:

```
range(1, 10, -1)
```

This starts at 1, and attempts to count backwards. There are no numbers between 1 and 9 counting backwards from 1 though, so you get an empty collection:

```
>>> list(range(1, 10, -1))
[]
```

You need to reverse the arguments as well:

```
>>> list(range(10, 1, -1))
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

you are facing the error because you are using `range` function in wrong manner.

`range(start, stop[, step])` -> range object

Here if step and start value is not provide then start value is consider as 0 by defualt and less than end value. also start is inclusive value and end is exclusive.

so in short `range(start, end, step)` -> start, start+step, start+step+step, ...., end-1`

in your code,

```
if num_1 > num_2:
   for i in range(num_1,num_2+1):
     # so on
```

here you are checking, `if num_1>num_2`, do `for` operation on `range(num_1. num_2)`, so since step is not defined by you, it is taken as 1 by default

now the `range(num_1, num_2)` become `[]` as `num_1 > num_2` and you cant reach num_2 by adding 1  to `num_1` continousily. ie  so `list(range(num_1, num_2))` is `[]`.

since it is empty for loop wont work and  it exit the program. same happen (in opposite manner) when `num_1<num_2`.

to solve this you need to provide the correct value in range or change the if conditions.

so solution be like this

```
if num_1 < num_2:
    for i in range(num_1,num_2+1):
        print(i)
else:
    for i in range(num_1,num_2,-1):
        print(i)
```